# Windows Server 2003 supports SQL Server 2008 Express edition?

Tags: windows-server-2003, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

I am wondering whether we could install SQL Server 2008 Express edition on Windows Server 2003? Or only SQL Server 2005 Express is supported on Windows Server 2003?

thanks in advance,
George

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. The complete requirements sheet at microsoft [site](http://www.microsoft.com/express/support/Default.aspx#sqlsysreq).

*SQL Server Express System Requirements*

**Supported Operating Systems**: Windows Server 2003 Service Pack 2; Windows Server 2008; Windows Vista; Windows Server 2008 R2; Windows 7; Windows Vista Service Pack 1; Windows XP Service Pack 2; Windows XP Service Pack 3;

**Physical Limitations** • 32-Bit Systems: Computer with Intel or compatible 1GHz or faster processor (2 GHz or faster is recommended. Only a single processor is supported.)
• 64-Bit systems: Computer with Intel or compatible 1.4 GHz or higher processor (2 GHz or faster is recommended. Only a single processor is supported.)
• Minimum of 512 MB of RAM (1 GB or more is recommended)
• 1.9GB of free hard disk space

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can happily install SQL 2008 Express on server 2003 ( so long as it is not Web Edition)